# Creating a dynamic class that inherit class it is made in

Tags: python

When I try to create a class from within a parent class, such that the child class inherits 'self', I get the following error:

`TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases`

```
class A(object):
    create_proxy = False

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(A, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.create_proxy:    
            class Proxy(SomeMixin, self):
                pass

            [...]
```

I'm sure this is somehow possible; any suggestions?

Comment: You probably want to have a look at the 3-argument form of `type()`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type

Comment: That's super interesting. However, how would I add a `Meta` class into a class created with `type()`? That is, `class Proxy(...): class Meta: proxy = True` (sorry about the formatting :/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the following change

```
...
if self.create_proxy:    
    class Proxy(SomeMixin, A): #use class name instead of self
        pass
...
```

Also make sure that `SomeMixin` is a subclass of `object`, otherwise it will result it metaclass conflict.

```
class SomeMixin(object):
    pass


class A(object):
    create_proxy = True #False
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(A, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.create_proxy:    
            class Proxy(SomeMixin, A):
                pass

a = A() #test
```